# pdflatex (texlive) tells me that "\homepage" is an 'undefined control sequence' when using moderncv

Tags: texlive, moderncv

I'm getting an error when trying to typeset my CV using `moderncv`. I'm doing this on Linux using `texlive` and when I try to compile it using `pdflatex` an error is returned at the `\homepage{}` line, specifically saying that it is an `undefined control sequence`. I've checked the [`moderncv` entry on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) and the `\homepage{}` entry is included in the example file, `template.tex`, but that when I try to compile that, it returns the same error. Is there something missing from `texlive` that's causing it not to work, or am I just missing something here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [changelog](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/CHANGELOG), `\homepage` was only added this May. Most Linux distributions don’t have recent enough TeX Live packages.

You can either install a new version of [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/), replacing the one from your package manager, our install a current version of `moderncv` from CTAN into your local texmf dir.